# Why does Faltings' Siegel lemma imply Siegel lemma?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, transcendental-number-theory

Recall the Siegel lemma:
Let $A = (a_{ij})$ be an $N \times M$ matrix with rational integer coefficients. Put $a = \max_{i,j} |a_{ij}|$. Then, if $N < M$, the equation $Ax = 0$ has a solution $x\in\mathbb Z^M$ , $x\ne0$, with
$‖x‖⩽(Ma)^{N/(M−N)}$ where $‖ ‖$ denotes the max-norm: $‖x‖=‖(x_1,...,x_M) ‖=\max_{1\le i\le M}|x_i| \in \mathbb R^M$.

In an article dated of 1992, Faltings proved this "version" of Siegel lemma:
Assume that we have two normed real vector spaces $V$ and $W$ with $\mathbb Z$-lattices $M$ and $N$, respectively, and a linear map
$\alpha: V\to W$ such that $\alpha(M)\subseteq N$. Let $C\ge2$ be a real number such that the map $\alpha$ has norm at most $C$, that $M$ is generated by elements of norm at most $C$ and that every non-zero element of $M$ and $N$ has norm at least $C^{-1}$. Then, for $a=\dim(\ker(\alpha))$, $b=\dim(V)$, and 
$U=\ker(\alpha)$ with the induced norm on $\ker(\alpha)$,
$$\lambda_{i+i}(U,U\cap M)=(C^{3b}b!)^{\frac1{a-i}}$$
for $0\le i\le a-1$. Here, for $V$ a finite dimensional normed real vector space with $\mathbb Z$-lattice $M$, one defines $\lambda_(V,M)$ as the smallest number $\lambda$ such that in $M$ there exist $i$ linearly independent vectors of norm not exceeding $\lambda$.

You can find all this stuff in
https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-48208-6_10

I do not see why Faltings lemma implies Siegel lemma (it appears that it is generalization...)

Comment: Read all about it in Jan Kooman's note: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pgmb0vleadfouf8/Faltings.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Hey there’s a typo —- it should be \lambda_{i+1}, not \lambda_{i+\ell}. Anywho take i=0, V = \R^M, W = \R^N, M = \Z^M [i.e., \Z^the M in the statement of the old Siegel lemma], N = \Z^N [same notational funny business], \alpha = (a_{ij}): V\to W, note that C = \max(a,2) is admissible (all nonzero vectors in \Z^d are of sup norm at least 1, M is generated by the standard basis, all of norm 1, and the image of \alpha is generated by the column vectors, all of norm at most a).

Comment: Argh sorry my phone deleted the rest of the comment! Anyway the bound that you get in the end is (a^3 M)^{M/(M-N)}, after using the easy M!\leq M^M and the similarly easy dim ker \alpha\geq M-N. The point is that in usual applications one takes M = (1+\delta) N with \delta > 0 a constant, and so the only difference between the two bounds is a constant in the exponent, which doesn’t make a difference in said applications.